# Convergence and calculation of a particular series.

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence

Let $$p_n(x)=\frac{x}{x+1}+\frac{x^2}{(x+1)(x^2+1)}+\frac{x^4}{(x+1)(x^2+1)(x^4+1)}+...…+\frac{x^{2^n}}{(x+1)(x^2+1)(x^4+1)(……)(x^{2^n}+1)}$$

I know this can be simplified to $$p_n(x)=1-\frac{1}{(x+1)(x^2+1)(x^4+1)(……)(x^{2^n}+1)}$$
Since it is only a telescoping series.

Evaluatie:$$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}p_n(x)=L$$

Now for $|x|\geq1; L=1$ and $x=0; L=0$

These two are quite obvious from a glance.

Now here's my question,

For $|x|< 1$, does $L$ converge and if it does how to calculate it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that
$$(x+1)(x^2+1)(x^4+1)\dots(x^{2^n}+1)=\dfrac{x^{2^{n+1}}-1}{x-1}$$
Therefore,
$$p_n(x)=1-\left(\dfrac{1-x}{1-x^{2^{n+1}}}\right)\xrightarrow{n\to\infty}x\qquad\forall\,|x|<1$$

Answer (score 0):

For $|x|<1$, the general term is such that

$$t_n<\frac{x^{2^n}}{1+x}.$$

For $x=1$,

$$t_n=\frac1{2^n}.$$